# Convert Nested Dictionary into Table/Parent Child Structure, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Want to convert nested Dictionary from the below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bundesbank.de/en/statistics/time-series-databases/time-series-databases/743796/openAll?treeAnchor=BANKEN&statisticType=BBK_ITS'
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

def get_child_nodes(parent_node):
    node_name = parent_node.a.get_text(strip=True)

    result = {"name": node_name, "children": []}

    children_list = parent_node.find('ul', recursive=False)
    if not children_list:
    return result

    for child_node in children_list('li', recursive=False):
    result["children"].append(get_child_nodes(child_node))

    return result

Data_Dict = get_child_nodes(soup.find("div", class_="statisticTree"))
```

Is it possible to export Parent - Child as shown in image?

[image]

Above code is from the Answer of @alecxe : [Fetch complete List of Items using BeautifulSoup, Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266718/fetch-complete-list-of-items-using-beautifulsoup-python-3-6)

I tried but its too complex to understand, Please help on the same.

Dictionary: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=97731876598977568058

Sample Dictionary Data:

```
{"name": "Banks", "children": [{"name": "Banks", "children": [{"name": "Balance sheet items", "children": 
[{"name": "Minimum reserves", "children": [{"name": "Reserve maintenance in the euro area", "children": []}, {"name": "Reserve maintenance in Germany", "children": []}]}, 

{"name": "Bank Lending Survey (BLS) - Results for Germany", "children": [{"name": "Lending", "children": [{"name": "Enterprises", "children": [{"name": "Changes over the past three months", "children": [{"name": "Credit standards and explanatory factors", "children": [{"name": "Overall", "children": []}, {"name": "Loans to small and medium-sized enterprises", "children": []}, {"name": "Loans to large enterprises", "children": []}, {"name": "Short-term loans", "children": []}, {"name": "Long-term loans", "children": []}]}, {"name": "Terms and conditions and explanatory factors", "children": [{"name": "Overall", "children": [{"name": "Overall terms and conditions and explanatory factors", "children": []}, {"name": "Margins on average loans and explanatory factors", "children": []}, {"name": "Margins on riskier loans and explanatory factors", "children": []}, {"name": "Non-interest rate charges", "children": []}, {"name": "Size of the loan or credit line", "children": []}, {"name": "Collateral requirements", "children": []}, {"name": "Loan covenants", "children": []}, {"name": "Maturity", "children": []}]}, {"name": "Loans to small and medium-sized enterprises", "children": []}, {"name": "Loans to large enterprises", "children": []}]}, {"name": "Share of enterprise rejected loan applications", "children": []}]}, {"name": "Expected changes over the next three months", "children": [{"name": "Credit standards", "children": []}]}]}, {"name": "Households", "children": [{"name": "Changes over the past three months", "children": [{"name": "Credit standards and explanatory factors", "children": [{"name": "Loans for house purchase", "children": []}, {"name": "Consumer credit and other lending", "children": []}]},
```

Comment: Since the conversion is just about dictionaries and has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup, please provide some sample data in a format that can be copy/pasted into Python, and remove the parts of the code which are unnecessary; make it a [mcve].

Comment: @kaya3, Updated sample Data, Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using a recursive function.

```
def get_pairs(data, parent=''):
    rv = [(data['name'], parent)]
    for d in data['children']:    
        rv.extend(get_pairs(d, parent=data['name']))
    return rv

Data_Dict = get_child_nodes(soup.find("div", class_="statisticTree"))

pairs = get_pairs(Data_Dict)
```

You then have the option of creating a DataFrame, or exporting to a csv immediately, as in your example output. To create a DataFrame, we can simply do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(get_pairs(Data_Dict), columns=['Name', 'Parent'])
```

Giving:

```
                                             Name               Parent
0                                           Banks                     
1                                           Banks                Banks
2                             Balance sheet items                Banks
3                                Minimum reserves  Balance sheet items
4            Reserve maintenance in the euro area     Minimum reserves
                                          ...                  ...
3890  Number of transactions per type of terminal  Payments statistics
3891   Value of transactions per type of terminal  Payments statistics
3892                   Number of OTC transactions  Payments statistics
3893                    Value of OTC transactions  Payments statistics
3894                        Issuance of banknotes  Payments statistics

[3895 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or to output to a csv, we can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) builtin library:

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('Name', 'Parent'))
    for pair in pairs:
        writer.writerow(pair)
```

Output:

[image]